# to disable authorize attribute in asp.net mvc by configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

For debugging pourpose i'm trying to disable the `[Authorize]` attribute on a controller by configuration (web.config)

so i added this to the web.config

```
<location path="ListaRichieste">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

whereas my controller name is `"ListaRichiesteController"`

this doesn't seem to work, so the points are:

- does the specific security configuration path has precendece of `[Authorize]` attribute?
- is the  correct?
- how can disable (temporary) the controller security without modify the controller code (i've a lot of controllers, i'm in a pseudo microservices architecture)
- override the `[Authorize]` attribute with a custom one is not a viable option form me because then i have to add this custom attribute to each project that contains the controller

  any idea how to achieve that by configuration or to limit the impact on the code of each controller/project/microservice

Answer (score 0):

You can't override this attribute by configuration, the best way in your case is to manually inject a loggued user in `HttpContext.User`. You could do it in your startup file with a `#if DEBUG`.

Something like this would do the work:

```
var username = "yourUsername";

GenericIdentity MyIdentity = new GenericIdentity(username ,AuthenticationTypes.Password); 
ClaimsIdentity objClaim = new ClaimsIdentity(AuthenticationTypes.Password, System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, "Recipient");

objClaim.Claims.Add(new Claim(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, username));
objClaim.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
objClaim.Name = username; 

GenericPrincipal MyPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(objClaim, new string[0]);
IPrincipal Identity = (IPrincipal)MyPrincipal; 

Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.User = Identity;
```

It's probably not the safest way, nor the best, but it's probably the most suitable one in your case.